# How do I make a launcher icon with a gradient background?

Tags: android, android-studio

The standard Android Image Studio only allows me to select a single color as the background for my icon. Is there a method for selecting two colors and creating a linear gradient effect?

[image]

Comment: Looking to do the same thing.  Looks like Android Studio generates the apps icons based on an image and a color.  Changing ic_launcher.xml does not re-generate the app icon pngs.  Anyone figure this out yet?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create an color_gradient.xml in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/start_gradient" <!--Start color of the gradient-->
                android:endColor="@color/end_gradient" <!--End color of the gradient-->
                android:angle="45" /> <!--Change this to see the combination of gradient color-->
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

When using for your image:

```
 android:backgroundTint="@drawable/color_gradient
```

**EDIT:**

In case of using Android Image Asset, you still can link the background color to this xml file, to create a gradient background

Comment: Thanks but I was asking about icon generation, not drawables.

Comment: @AlanSTACK How do you generate icon? creating a svg file?

Comment: @AlanSTACK Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @AlanSTACK glad it helps

Comment: So to update the backgroudcolor to your gradient color you update in ic_launcher.xml: <background android:drawable="@drawable/color_gradient"/>

Comment: @WiRa is that a question?

Comment: @WiRa Changing ic_launcher.xml does not regenerate the app icon png's.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Change the app icon](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-change-app-icon#0) example doc:

> the Android platform introduced support for adaptive icons (as of API
> level 26). By implementing an adaptive icon for your app, your app is
> able to accommodate a large range of devices by tailoring the launcher
> icon based on a device's display

In res folder, create a `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder, create `ic_launcher.xml` file and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"/>
  <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
  <monochrome android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_monochrome"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Here as you see, above we need three drawable that we need to put in all other mipmap folders

1. `ic_launcher_background.png` is the gradient background image
2. `ic_launcher_foreground.png` is the main icon/logo with transparent background.
3. `ic_launcher_monochrome.png` is the monochrome version of `ic_launcher_foreground` to support monochrome ui adaptation in android.

It is done.
You can use websites like [IconKitchen](https://icon.kitchen/) to generate everything mentioned above and copy paste in your res folder.